# Error: The view or its master was not found. The following locations were searched

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with a particular controller action not displaying the view.

Here is the Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult DisplayStudents(string id)
        {
            var name = (from p in data.StudentTable.Where(a => a.ClassNumberID == id)
                                  group n by n.StudentName into g
                                  select g.Key).First();

            return View(name);
        }
```

Controller Name is "Student" and the view is present in "Views/Student/DisplayStudents.aspx"

Why do I still get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The view 'Thomas Guenn' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Student/Thomas Guenn.aspx
~/Views/Student/Thomas Guenn.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Thomas Guenn.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Thomas Guenn.ascx
```

Also, why is it looking for "Thomas Guenn.aspx" instead of "DisplayStudents.aspx" ?

Here is my View page:

> >" %>
>
> DisplayStudents  
>       
>       Students are listed below:
>
> ```
> <table>
>
> <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
>      <tr>
>         <td>
>             <%= Html.Encode(item)%>
>         </td>
>     </tr>
>
> <% } %>
>
> </table> </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: If you put a break point in the controller, are you hitting the action you are expecting?

Comment: can you show your routes, and the url being requested? this looks like a routing problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `View(name);` call is calling overload `View(string viewName)`. If you want to pass string as Model then try using

```
return View((object)name);
```

instead.

If this doesn't work, try to specify viewName explicitly, using overload `View(string viewName, object model)` like this:

```
return View("DisplayStudents", name);
```

**UPD:** Looking at your view code, I can say that it won't return expected page either: you're returning a single string item as a model from controller, but your `DisplayStudents.aspx` expects a collection. You should also either correct your view (so it will accept single string as model) or return an `IEnumerable<string>` from controller - by removing `.First()` from LINQ expression for `name`.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the overload expects an object if it is data, and a string if you are passing the name of the view in.

Use this instead:

```cs
return View((object)name);
```